# Updating Certificates on OpenShift + Kubernetes 4.6+

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, openshift, okd

Evening!

I'm wondering if anyone could share the steps for updating the certificates on OpenShift + Kubernetes 4.6?  I've checked using the below command and some are expired.

`find /etc/kubernetes/ -type f -name "*.crt" -print|egrep -v 'ca.crt$'|xargs -L 1 -t  -i bash -c 'openssl x509  -noout -text -in {}|grep After'`

I'm not able to find relevant steps to my UPN install.  The following certificates are expired as well.

`81789506 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   59 Jan  9 00:32 kubelet-server-current.pem -> /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-server-2021-06-18-20-35-33.pem 81800208 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   59 Jan  9 00:32 kubelet-client-current.pem -> /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-2021-06-19-13-16-00.pem`

Since the API server is offline, I'm not able to renew the certificates via oc commands.  All OC commands return an error since the API server ( port 6443 ) is offline. This cluster is installed on VMware using the UPI method. There was a failure sometime back taking the cluster offline.  When the cluster was brought back up, the certs were already expired and could not renew since services needed for that were offline I think?

Wondering if anyone managed to recover from this scenario and would be able to help?

Comment: "_Wondering if anyone managed to recover from this scenario_", yes, it is possible to recover from such by in example recreating the PKI and which would be a more complex process. Because of OpenShift, Red Hat Support can help here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the official doc on that subject?
It may help you
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/backup_and_restore/control_plane_backup_and_restore/disaster_recovery/scenario-3-expired-certs.html
But if you can't login to your cluster, it may be quite difficult...

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I did come across it earlier.  All the OC commands fail.  All cluster members are offline, however I'm seeing etcd db corruption.  This is apparently preventing the api server from starting up and renewing anything.  I'm trying to see how to restore the ETCD DB instead from what appears to be a single non corrupted member db, while trying to dig through log files for more specifics:

https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/recovery/

More updates to follow.

Comment: You also have some doc on how to restore etcd in OCP here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/backup_and_restore/control_plane_backup_and_restore/disaster_recovery/scenario-2-restoring-cluster-state.html